# Max of each subgroup in a group

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, relational-database

So I have a table with following data :

```
X------------------Y
customer1------A
customer1------A
customer1------B
customer2------B
customer2------B
customer2------B
customer2------C
customer2------C
customer2------C
customer2------C
customer2------C
```

So I need to find what max(Y) does each customer have. So customer1 must have B and customer2 must have C (I'm using postgresql)

Comment: If there are duplicates, then what?

Comment: what do you mean by duplicates?

Comment: Isn't this just a max and group by? `SELECT x, max(y) y
FROM table
GROUP BY X`  I'm probably under thinking/enginering it though.

Comment: @kkr . . . If two `Y` values appear the same, maximum number of times.

Comment: @kkr  do you have what you need? or is this question yet open?

Answer (score 0):

You want the "mode" in statistics.  Here is one method to get exactly one value per x (ignoring duplicates):

```
select distinct on (x) x, y
from (select x, y, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by x, y
     ) xy
order by x, cnt desc;
```

Comment: I don't think it's a max based on count. Customer 1 must have "B"  in the sample customer 1 has b once and A twice.  So I think he just want's max of Y; which seems really odd but...  All I can think of is that the question is over simplified and Y must be a date or a numeric progression; otherwise max of a string seems odd.

Comment: @xQbert . . . It makes perfect sense to me that the OP is trying to ask for the mode -- the most common value in the column.  I can see, though, that the question is not that clear.